# Can I cut tempered glass with diamond circular saw blade?

Tags: glass, cutting

This is safety glass, but it's very old glass <1994. So probably not the kind that will smash, but kite mark should tell you if it does.

I want to make a new door for my greenhouse out of it if I can, but that of course means cutting it down.

[image]

Comment: I would enlarge the door opening or I see a big mess in your future.

Comment: No can do - the glass is far too big for that. But to be fair I was expecting an answer along the lines of "you can't"

Comment: Why does <1994 mean it won't smash? Toughened glass smashes - that's what it does. I love the fact that 1994 is considered "very old", as well!

Comment: Ha, well, it is 26 years ago! :) I mean it has been dumped at the allotment since at least that year according to people who have been there that long - it could be decades older, I thought the maker's mark would give a clue there. I guess I thought that the safety feature of smashing was more recent than 1994, too.

Answer (score 4):

Safety glass is either tempered, laminated (with plastic layers for shard retention), wired with mesh, or a combination. Rarely can any of them be cut without detonation. I would not attempt it without substantial safety gear.

Comment: One more thought.  If you ever have to replace a piece of tempered glass (fireplace door, car window, patio table), they need to measure and cut the glass first, then run it through the tempering process.

Comment: +1 for "Detonation". I had a car windscreen shatter as I walked past it once - it made a hell of a bang.